# How to keep a promise working even after updating the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

When I go on my Logout page, I issue a request to my Laravel server in order to delete the token from the user profile. However, it automatically redirects me to "/" without doing the promise.

I don't really understand what is going on there.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import Axios from 'axios';

export class Logout extends Component {
    render() {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/logout', {}, {headers: {Accept: 'application/json', Authorization: 'Bearer ' . Cookies.get('token')}}).then((success) => {
            Cookies.remove('token');
            //this.props.history.push("/");
            console.log('test')
        })
        console.log('test 2')
        return <p>Déconnexion...</p>
    }
}

export default withRouter(Logout)
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Navigation from './components/navigation/Navigation'
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage'
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard'
import NoMatch from './pages/NoMatch'
import Register from './pages/register/Register'
import RegisterVolunteer from './pages/register/RegisterVolunteer'
import RegisterOrganism from './pages/register/RegisterOrganism'
import EmailConfirmation from './pages/register/EmailConfirmation';
import EmailConfirmed from './pages/register/EmailConfirmed';
import Login from './pages/login/Login'
import DashboardHomepage from './pages/dashboard/DashboardHomepage';
import UserProfile from './pages/user/UserProfile'
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'
import Logout from './pages/Logout'

//export const RequestContext = React.createContext('http://localhost:8000');

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      //<RequestContext.Provider>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute path="/profil">
                <UserProfile />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute path="/tableaudebord">
                <DashboardHomepage />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute reverse="true" path="/inscription">
                <Register />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute reverse="true" path="/inscription/benevole">
                <RegisterVolunteer />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute reverse="true" path="/connexion">
                <Login />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute reverse="true" path="/inscription/organisme">
                <RegisterOrganism />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute path="/deconnexion">
                <Logout />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <Route exact path={["/inscription/verifier-email"]} component={EmailConfirmation} />
              <Route exact path={["/inscription/email-confirme"]} component={EmailConfirmed} />
              <Route exact path={["/", "/accueil"]} component={Homepage} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      //</RequestContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'


export function PrivateRoute({ children, reverse = false, ...rest }) {
    if(reverse) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={({ location }) =>
            (Cookies.get('token') == undefined) ? (
                children
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: "/tableaudebord",
                    state: { from: location }
                }}
                />
            )
            }
        />
        );
    }
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={({ location }) =>
          (Cookies.get('token') != undefined) ? (
            children
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/connexion",
                state: { from: location }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }

export default PrivateRoute
```

Here is also an error code I get :

Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Thank you so much !

Comment: you shouldn't make api call in render function, use `componentDidMount`  in `Logout` component to delete the token, and in api callback redirect user to homepage or somewhere else.

Comment: @hussain.codes the only issue is that componentDidMount is called in the router, even if I am not on the Logout page.. I don’t want it to delete the token each time I refresh the page.